# C++ Range concept for stream-like ranges?

Tags: c++, range

With C++ ranges we can describe streams such as, for example, an input stream which iterator could be a `std::istream_iterator`.
Such iterator complies with the `std::input_iterator` concept. So such range would also comply with an `std::ranges::input_range` concept.
Now I don't see any concept that describes the specificity of a stream, in the sense that calling `begin()` returns the current iterator of where the stream is. So incrementing this iterator and calling `begin()` again will not issue the same iterator.

I see this kind of concept useful, in functions like serializers/deserializers that can be composed of independents functions that process each values in a sequence.

Is there any thing in C++ that could describe such concept? Or any plans, discussion to do so?

EDIT 1: This could be the use case:

```cpp
template <input_stream_range T>
void deserialize(T&& t, Output& o)
{
    deserialize_int32(t, o.value_int);
    deserialize_string(t, o.value_string);
    ...
}
```

`deserialize_int32` and `deserialize_string` can also be used independently. This concept would allow composition of such functions.
This could be solved by passing the iterators directly to the function, but in that case I would have to create 2 overloads for the same function each time (one for the iterator, one for the range), which is quite redundant.

Comment: what would be the benefit of repeadetly calling `begin` rather than calling it once and incrementing the returned iterator?

Comment: Thanks @463035818_is_not_a_number, I have added an edit to my question that hopefully addresses your comment.